# Custom UITableViewCell with drawRect + normal blue selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell. All the drawing is done in the drawRect: method and no subviews are added.
The drawing works fine and the scroll speed is good.
But the problem is with the selected cells. I want the selection to behave like it would normally:

- Blue gradient selection color
- Inverted text color
- Animated deselection

I have not been able to achieve all three.

**First attempt:**
Set selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone and do the selection color in the drawRect method.
With this method, I am able to achieve the first two things, but the deselection is instant. So one second it is selected blue, the next second it is deselected. I do not get the nice fade-out.

**Second attempt:**
selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue
With this method my cell is all gradient blue when selected. The text I have is not visible. The fade-out works nicely, though.

**Third attempt:**
Set selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue and also set selectedBackgroundView to a UIView where I set the backgroundColor to a transparent blue.
Here the problem is that the selectedBackgroundView (despite the name) is drawn on top of my normal content. So if the selectedBackgroundView is not transparent, I cannot see the text. And if it is transparent, I can see the text, but the selection color gets "faded" and does not look right.

**What would be the correct way of achieving all three bullet points?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So the answer to my own question... Don't subclass UITableViewCell for custom drawing. Instead subclass a UIImageView or a UIView.

This post has a nice description of how to do it:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the second attempt in combination with a gesture recognizer. Check if the user presses on a cell, if so, set the textcolor in that cell to yellow (or what is the inversion of blue? xD).

Sample code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        //do something with that view, for example: 
        //change the color of the text in that view, 
        //or invert it ;)
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Alternatively, you can attach a UIGestureRecognizer to that button. That way, you get the class called inserted in the selector.

There might be a better option to do what you asked. This just came up my mind, if you have 2/3 points working already, this should help you to get 3/3.

Comment: The problem is not that the text color should be inverted. It is normally black, but that is not visible either. The problem seems to be that the blue gradient is not transparent. I also have an image in my cell and that is not visible either when selected. So this suggestion will not work.