# Overriding drawRect in ios7 fails

Tags: overriding, uinavigationbar, ios7

For a custom layout in iOS6, i have created a subclass of UINavigationBar and overridden the drawRect method. I specify the class in interface builder, because not every controller needs to have this effect. This is also the reason why i cannot use a category.

But now with iOS7, i want to use the default navigationbar and not the overriden behaviour. The code below does not work:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if([self isOS7]) {
       [super drawRect:rect];
    } 
    else {
        // custom drawing
    }
}
```

The problem is, by actually defining the drawRect, ios7 fails to correctly draw the navigation bar under the status bar. If i leave out the entire drawrect, it works (but then it doesn't work under older devices!

Any suggestions?

Comment: drawRect, isn't called... right? I have the same problem

Comment: Did you find a solution/workaround? I can imagine the caller is checking a `respondsToSelector:` somewhere...

Comment: Seams to be a bug!
When you remove the whole method and start with ios7, it works.
super drawRect:rect doesn't work... so it seams that it's not possible to override this method in io7 correctely. Do you agree?

Comment: @Sam, that was the whole point of my post...

Comment: Sorry i missed the last sentence :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it, if you add a new UIView as a Subview and do the stuff there instead in draw rect.

[UITableViewCell drawInRect iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905917/uitableviewcell-drawinrect-ios7)

Comment: That is an interesting approach, I will try it.